# How to convert Double (or Float) to Byte (or Short) in Kotlin 1.4?

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion

In Kotlin version 1.4 the functions `toByte()` and `toShort()` are missing for `Float` and `Double` data types. How to convert those to `Short` or `Byte`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the official docs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/?_ga=2.260424973.1686486812.1586697539-1585032741.1578135877) state:

> Conversions of floating-point numbers to Short and Byte could lead to
>   unexpected results because of the narrow value range and smaller
>   variable size.

So if you want to convert to `Byte` or `Short`, you should do two steps: first convert to `Int` (with `toInt()`) and then to the target type (e.g. `toShort()`).

For instance: **`myVar.toInt().toByte()`**